# hive, get the data location using an one-liner

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore

I wonder if there is a way to get the data location from hive using a one-liner.  Something like

```
select d.location from ( describe formatted table_name partition ( .. ) ) as d;
```

My current solution is to get the full output and then parse it.

Comment: You mean location of your table?

Comment: yes, the table/partition location.

Comment: On the other hand, you can use the MetaStore Java API to build your own app, and get the relevant `StorageDescriptor` in 72 easy steps... Just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike traditional RDBMS, Hive metadata is stored in a separate database. In most cases it is in MySQL or Postgres. The metastore database details can be found in hive-site.conf. If you have access to the metastore database, you can run SELECT on table TBLS to get the details about the tables and COLUMNS_V2 to get the details about columns etc..

If you do not have access to the metastore, the only option is to describe each table to get the details. If you have a lot of databases and tables, you could write a shell script to get the list of tables using "show tables" and loop around the tables.

Comment: I wonder if it is not the case to add some way to query the metastore from hive.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods if you do not have access to the metadata.

Parse `DESCRIBE TABLE` in the shell like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804621/2700344

Also Hive has a virtual column INPUT__FILE__NAME.

```
select INPUT__FILE__NAME from table
```

will output locations URLs for each file.
You can split URL by '/', get element you need, aggregate, etc

Comment: Your statement will output the files which will be sent to the mapper: bad idea. It's a huge and verbose output. I'm afraid the only option is to parse the output from describe formatted. It still bad "to parse", but it's the only option.