# How can I know all external tables that have same location in Hive?

Tags: hive, hive-metastore

I serve a Hadoop echo system as a Data Engineer.

I manage a data source as just columnar storage file formats like parquet.

Besides of data source, I make Hive table external table and just refer to a data source as location.

My question. I want to investigate which tables are affected by changing something of a data source.

Is there a command or query to investigate this? (get all external tables that refer to a target location)

Comment: If you do not have access directly to Hive metastore database, then you can use shell script to iterate tables and get their locations like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804621/2700344

Comment: @leftjoin I cannot access the database of the metastore. I only can query to it.